# How to transition from UITableViewCell to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to go from a UITableView with prototype cells to a `detailviewcontroller` of the item I selected on.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"historyToDetail"])
    {
        BYFHistoryDetailViewController *controller = (BYFHistoryDetailViewController    *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc] init];
        controller.workOut=_selectRow;
    }
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BYFHistoryTableViewController *detailViewController =[[BYFHistoryTableViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *items = [[BYFworkOutStore sharedStore] allItems];
    BYFWorkOut *selectedItem = items[indexPath.row];
    _selectRow = selectedItem;
}
```

What is not happening is the transition from the table to detail I have a push segue from the prototype cell to the details.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing quite a lot wrong here. When using segue's you don't create an instance of the class. You simply call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
```

This will use the segue you have defined in the storyboard. Where `MySegue` is the segue ID you created.

When you want to pass in data you use the callback

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    BYFHistoryDetailViewController *vc = (BYFHistoryDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    vc.workOut = selectedItem;
}
```

But using this callback will mean you will need to store `selectedItem` somewhere after you click the row so you can access it here.

**EDIT**

Your code seems a bit odd here also.

You set workout to a new object.

```
detailViewController.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init];
```

Create another object from data.

```
NSArray *items = [[BYFworkOutStore sharedStore] allItems];
BYFWorkOut *selectedItem = items[indexPath.row];
```

And then assign the new object, overwriting the previous one.

```
//give detail view controller a pointer to the item object in row
detailViewController.workOut = selectedItem;
```

There is no need to have the first line of code at all

**EDIT 2**

If you only going to be using the one selected item at a time. you can do this in your `UITableViewController` class.

```
@implementation MyTableViewControllerClass
{
    BYFWorkOut *_selectedItem;
}
```

inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSArray *items = [[BYFworkOutStore sharedStore] allItems];
   _selectedItem = items[indexPath.row];
}
```

---

---

**EDIT 3**

I've modified the code you posted here. You didn't add the first line of code i posted. Please look at this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"historyToDetail"])
    {
        BYFHistoryDetailViewController *controller = (BYFHistoryDetailViewController    *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.workOut = _selectRow;
    }
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *items = [[BYFworkOutStore sharedStore] allItems];
    _selectRow = items[indexPath.row];

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"historyToDetail" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: would creating a property for selected item be a easy/correct way to store it?

Comment: @user3431724 added more to my answer, see EDIT 2

Comment: @user3431724 a property would work fine, but if its only going to be accessed / used by this class (ignoring passing through), theres no need, the edit I showed is how to create a private variable. Makes more sense in this context

Comment: about my code seeming a bit odd in another section of my code i pass values using the segue but it does not work without alloc and init first because (i think correct me if im wrong) you cannot write to it unless it has been created and it would be created in viewDidLoad but that view has not been loaded yet because of lazy loading protocall  so we must create it in the segue then assign the valuei will change it to be private however im still not getting the segue to work

Comment: @user3431724 I edited your code in EDIT 3 to my answer. You didn't call the segue, which was the very first line of code I posted. And no i'm sorry thats no correct at all. All objects are pointers. What you are doing is creating an object and passing its memory location to another pointer. Whether the second pointer was pointing to a memory location, or nil, has no bearing what so ever in regards to passing data. The end result is exactly the same. Creating it first is just wasted processing

Comment: well guess i still have alot more to learn! thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You need to name your segue and call the method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
```